# How is "chromium-chromedriver" package used?

Tags: python, firefox, chromium, selenium

Firefox selenium driver seems to be crashing (perhaps because I'm on Firefox-beta ppa?):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> webdriver.Firefox
<class 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver'>
>>> webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

So I tried installing the chromium driver but it still fails with selenium:

```
>>> webdriver.Chrome()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 66, in start
    "ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
```

Am I missing something or is this package completely broken? I have both Chromium and Google Chrome installed for testing, if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

- The Firefox webdriver failed with this message:

  > "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect"

  Which means that selenium managed to find it. I also believe that beta versions can be the root cause as it works out of the box for me using the repo version.
- For Chromium, you have to install the following packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-selenium chromium-chromedriver
  ```

  And fix the `libui_base.so` library path (See [Chromedriver on Ubuntu 14.04 - error while loading shared libraries: libui_base.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695299/chromedriver-on-ubuntu-14-04-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libui-base))
- To use the Chrome [webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) install the following dependency:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-selenium
  ```

  And download the Chromedriver from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.14/), select the one corresponding to your architecture e.g:

  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_linux64.zip
  or http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_linux32.zip

  Extract the `chromedriver` file for example in your `$HOME` folder.

  Then to start the chromedriver from python, open a terminal and type:

  ```
  $ python
  Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
  [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import os
  >>> from selenium import webdriver
  >>> driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.expanduser('~/chromedriver'))
  ```

Finally I'd recommend to use the package version of `python-selenium` available from the Ubuntu repositories to avoid installation in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: `sudo pip install --upgrade selenium` should do it.